# Splitting a Large Dataframe into multiple df's with no more than 'x' number of rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying the most pythonic way of splitting a Dataframe (of varying sizes) into smaller dataframes of not more than 15000 rows.

Background is - I am using API calls to write a dataframe to a server. The process fails if send the whole dataframe (if large). Hence, I thought we could just loop over the split dataframe.

Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order does not matter, you can use a [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) with a stepsize:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

data = np.random.rand(1_000_000, 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# how many rows we allow per dataframe
max_rows = 150_000

# how many subsets we need
stepsize = math.ceil(len(df) / max_rows)

# create a list of subsets
dfs = [df.iloc[offset::stepsize] for offset in range(stepsize)]

for small_df in dfs:
    print(len(small_df))
```

You can also use a generator to prevent holding the list of subsets in memory. Here's a variation which uses a generator and preserves order:

```py
def small_dfs(df, max_rows):
    n = math.ceil(len(df) / max_rows)
    for ix in range(n):
        yield df.iloc[ix * max_rows : (ix+1) * max_rows, :]

for small_df in small_dfs(df, 150_000):
    print(len(small_df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list that stores the ranges you need, then loop through and index the dataframes. This might not be the most efficient, but it is fairly readable.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# random data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Example'] = np.random.rand(100000)

# get length of dataframe
l = len(df)
# get list of ranges, in steps of 15,000
splits = np.arange(0,l,15000)

# a dictionary to hold the smaller dataframes
dataframes_split_up = {}

# split up the larger dataframe
for i,s in enumerate(splits):
    if i == len(splits)-1:
        dataframes_split_up[i] = df[splits[i]:]
    else:
        dataframes_split_up[i] = df[splits[i]:splits[i+1]]
```

Output is a dictionary of dataframes no larger than 15,000 rows.

```
print([len(x[1]) for x in dataframes_split_up.items()])
>>>> [15000, 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000, 15000, 10000]
```